# How to read web.config Connection string section from session?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to read `web.config` `connection string` section from session?

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnectionString" connectionString="session["Connection"].ToString()" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You cannot. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: If you, by any chance, is trying to have a dynamic connectionstring, just create another one, with a different name, and based on your checks, just call the other connection string

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem to me.  What are you *really* trying to accomplish here?  If you tells us why you want to do this, we can help you find a more appropriate way to solve it. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I need it for logging. I want use  current_user in trigger to know which user deleted records. So every user that login in my website must connect to database with it`s SQL user. I create a user in SQL server for every my website users